# How to change widget background color?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
def change_frame_color(self, r, g, b):
    widget_list = [self.ui.widget,self.ui.widget_2,self.ui.widget_3,self.ui.widget_4,self.ui.widget_5]

    for widget in widget_list:
        widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        pt = widget.palette()
        pt.setColor(widget.backgroundRole(),QColor(r,g,b))
        widget.setPalette(pt)
        p = widget.palette().color(QPalette.Background)
        print(p.name(), widget.autoFillBackground())
        widget.update()
```

this is my code....

palette change but QWidget not change :(